# Where is API doc for the platforms

Tags: android

I installed  sdk platform and Google APIs for android 2.2 with SDK manager but where is that API docs, I want to browse those APIs offline, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get all the documentation in Docs folder which is inside of your Android SDK folder. If it is not there then you must have not installed the Docs. Go to Android SDK Manager and check the Documentation for Android SDK option for Android 2.2. Then install selected packages.

Comment: I have the Docs folder filled with many file, which one is for my platform APIs ?

Comment: I cant find the APIs for my platform. I cant find any component named Framework API under Android 2.2 in SDK manager. Then how do I get an offline API docs for my platform

Comment: just open index.html page and use it as if you are using developer.android.com.  In that page click on Develop tab then select reference. You will see a list of APIs in left side. At the top of the list you can select API level whatever you want and respective APIs will get displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can find docs for Android Platform in

> sdk/docs

folder

Comment: There are many files in doc dir, I just want the APIs for my platform- 2.2

Comment: It contains detail of every Android call or we can say you can access developer.android.com offline.. you can open index.html and search for the class or function while you are offline

Comment: Yes I found the folders but I cant find the APIs for my platform. I cant find any component named Framework API under Android 2.2 in SDK manager. Then how do I get an offline API docs for my platform

Comment: M searching for android 2.1/2.2 API 7/8